# USERPROFILE as Default Location

Tags: visual-studio

Can one use a folder that includes USERPROFILE as Default location in Visual Studio setup?

By default it shows as

```
[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

Changing `[ProgramFilesFolder]` to `[USERPROFILE]` like the one shown below doesn't seem to work

```
C:\Users\[USERPROFILE]\AppData\Roaming\CarriageWay
```

It does creates create a folder but it doesn't go to its intended target, totally ignores the "userprofile" name, say Ricardo for one. It may be any name.

```
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\CarriageWay
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, one needs to include "User's Application Data Folder" under File System on Target Machine [AppDataFolder] and add folders under that.

Not to be confused with the Default location under Applications folder.